# Need help identifying teen novel about virtual reality game and AI

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

So I read this story 3-4 years ago, and I remember it being average novel length, but I cannot find it. All I remember is that the main character is best friends with the guy that invented the first virtual reality game. He is dragged into it by his friend and play on his friend's team. Then there are government spies for some reason (I don't remember why) and the main character ends up falling in love with one of his team mates who turns out to be an AI.

I'm pretty sure this is all set in the US and at least one of the spies is from the Australian government and the main character is a struggling freelance writer. The main character's mom is on life support and he's the only one paying for it. And one of the people on the team had a pet salamander thing in the game.

Comment: Can you recall any other details about this?

Comment: Yeah I've been thinking about it some more I'll put what I think I remember in there now

Comment: Can you remember even roughly how old the book is, or how long ago you read it? Anything about the author? The names of any important characters or events? Such details could make a big difference.

Comment: I read the story 3-4 years ago, and I remember it being average novel length. Other than that I can't recall anything new at the moment. If I do I will definitely update though.